# Genetic Algorithms - N Queen Problem - Diagonal Conflicts

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, n-queens

Im working on a Java based code on Genetic Algorithms. I want to solve the N-queen problem and need to calculate conflicts/clashes in the diagonal. I am unable to find the clashes in the diagonal properly.

I have found an algorithm but can not understand it properly that how it implements on my code.
I generate a 2d Array of 8x8

```
char Queens[][]={
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},

            };
```

I already found the clashes for Columns and Rows. Just need to calculate diagonal clashes.

```
 for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            Queens[myarr[i]][i] = 'q';
        }

int conflict=0;
        for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<8;j++){
                if(Queens[i][j]=='q'){




                    for(int left=j-1;left>=0;left--){
//                        System.out.print(left+"      "+j);
                        if(Queens[i][left]=='q'){
                            conflict++;
                        }
                    }


                        for(int right=j+1;right<8;right++)
                        {
                               if(Queens[i][right]=='q'){
                                conflict++;
                            }
                        }
```

This is an algorithm i found but unable to implement it on my `Queens[][]` Array

```
# calculate diagonal clashes
for i in range(len(chromosome)):
    for j in range(len(chromosome)):
        if ( i != j):
            dx = abs(i-j)
            dy = abs(chromosome[i] - chromosome[j])
            if(dx == dy):
                clashes += 1


return 28 - clashes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

- The code counts the conflicts twice. That's not necessary because if there is a conflict between `q1` and `q2`, there is also a conflict between `q2` and `q1` for *reasons of symmetry*. In principle, it is therefore sufficient to count in *only one* direction, either to the left or to the right. Programmatically, this means that only one of the two inner loops should be used (either the one with the `right`-counter or the one with the `left`-counter).

  Therefore, the first change should be to remove one of the inner loops. This also makes sense for performance reasons.
- The second problem is that currently only the conflicts within the *same row* are counted, but not the conflicts within the *same column*.

  Therefore, the second change should be the consideration of conflicts within the same column. Programmatically it is similar to the previous case, but now you have to think in the categories *top and bottom* instead of *left and right*.
- The next problems concerns the consideration of the conflicts on the diagonals (which is the original question).

  Your pseudo code concerning the diagonal conflicts is probably from [here](https://kushalvyas.github.io/gen_8Q.html). In this approach, a solution candidate is regarded as a chromosome with `n` genes. Each gene corresponds to one line of the `nxn`-chessboard and indicates the position of the queen in that line. I.e. a solution candidate corresponds to an array of the size `n`, in which each element contains the position of the queen in the line belonging to the respective element.

  In contrast, your code uses a `nxn`-matrix that represents the chessboard directly. This means that a solution candidate corresponds to a `nxn`-matrix, in which every element that corresponds to a field with a queen contains the character `q`.

  I don't see how you can combine the pseudo code with your approach. That's why I suggest the following alternative which is compatible with your approach:

  There are two categories of diagonals:

  - One category includes the diagonals from top left to bottom right. This case can be handled as follows:

    ```
    for (int bottom = i + 1, right = j + 1; bottom < 8 && right < 8; bottom++, right++) {
        if (Queens[bottom][right] == 'q') {
            conflict++;
        }
    }
    ```
  - The other category includes the diagonals from top right to bottom left. Programmatically, this resembles the previous case
    and can therefore be implemented in an analogous way.

After making all the changes, there are a total of four inner loops. The first takes into account the conflicts within the rows, the second within the columns, and the third and fourth within the diagonals. A test with the following matrix...

```
{ 'q', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'q' }, 
{ '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
{ '.', '.', 'q', '.', '.', 'q', '.', '.' }, 
{ '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
{ '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' }, 
{ '.', '.', 'q', '.', '.', 'q', '.', '.' },
{ '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' }, 
{ 'q', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'q' },
```

...should result in 20 conflicts (2 diagonals with 6 = 3+2+1 conflicts each, 4 rows with 1 conflict each, and 4 columns with 1 conflict each: 2*6 + 4*1 + 4*1 = 20).

Comment: This seems to be the perfect explanation. I went through all your suggestions and going to update you about them soon.

Comment: Also, does a solution set converge to same number of conflicts if a small population (i.e 5) is used for initiating?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. In the `n` queens problem, `n` queens on an `nxn`-board are to be arranged without conflicts. For each `n` there is a number of solutions, e.g. in case `n = 8` there are 92 solutions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle). If the question is whether this number of solutions is the same if `m < n` queens are placed on an `nxn`-board, then you can consider e.g. the cases `n = 2` and `n = 8`. The case `n = 2` has 0 solutions. But if you arrange `m = 1 < n = 2` queens on an `nxn`-board there are `n*n = 4 > 0` solutions.

Comment: The case `n = 8` has 92 solutions. If you arrange `m = 1 < n = 8` queens on an `nxn`-board there are `n*n = 64 < 92` solutions. Similar considerations can also be made for `1 < m < n`. Although I am not a mathematician, I dare say the answer to the question is generally no.